# Intuition/meaning of information geometry distances and geodesics?

Tags: normal-distribution, fisher-information, information-geometry

In information geometry, we consider a manifold of probability distributions, together with  the Fisher Information metric (given by the Fisher Information matrix).

I have some intuition (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information_metric#Relation_to_the_Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)) for what the metric means locally, i.e. the length of infinitesimal vector $d \theta$ on tangent space of point $\theta$, as given by the metric, approximates the KL divergence between $P(X|\theta)$ and $P(X|\theta + d\theta)$ (if this intuition can be expressed more precisely, feel free to make suggestions).

However, it is not clear to me what is the meaning or intuition of the distance between points that is obtained by integrating this metric. That is, when we have two points $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ in the manifold, what is the meaning of the Fisher information distance between the two? Furthermore, is there some intuition or statistical interpretation of what is the geodesic between these points? Is it in some way like a "least-discriminable" path between the two, or something such?

A [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/using-information-geometry-to-define-distances-and-volumes-useful/2796#2796) from 10 years ago asked whether there's anything useful about these distances. Here I'm not asking whether there's something useful about them, but about their interpretation.

I'm specifically interested in the case of Gaussians, and more specifically, 0-centered Gaussians, where we have closed form for the [Fisher distance](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25050283) and geodesics:

$d(A,B)^2 = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^p (\log \lambda_i)^2 = ||log (A^{-1/2}B A^{-1/2})||^2$

where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$'th generalized eigenvalue of the matrix pair $(A,B)$, and $||\cdot ||$ is the Frobenius norm. From this, it seems like the distance is strongly related to the discriminability between the distributions, given the squared log of the generalized eigenvalues.